# find next Date in DateTimePicker control

Tags: c#

I can get **Today** `DateTime` from `DateTimePicker` control. Now I want to have all the dates between 2 specific dates, such as `2014/6/25` until `2014/7/3.`

*I know the traditional way to break down the date's string to char then find the month 
number and increase the day until 31 or 30.*

**Is there any easier way to do that?**

Comment: **1)** Get these dates as `startDate` and `endDate`. **2)** Use for loop starts `startDate` until the `endDate` and increase your `startDate` with `.AddDays(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>();

var startDate = new DateTime(2014, 6, 25);
var endDate = new DateTime(2014,7,3);
while(startDate <= endDate)
{
   dates.Add(startDate);
   startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

LINQ way:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2014, 6, 25);
var endDate = new DateTime(2014,7,3);
var difference = (endDate - startDate).Days;
var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, difference+1)
      .Select(d => startDate.AddDays(d))
      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `for` loop?

```
List<DateTime> myDates = new List<DateTime>();

DateTime startDate = new DateTime (2014, 6, 25);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime (2014,7,3);

for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
  myDates.Add(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days; i++)
{
    DateTime temp = startDate.AddDays(i);
}
```

with AddDays you don't have to take care about overflow:

```
2014-2-28 -> AddDays(1) -> 2014-3-1
2012-2-18 -> AddDays(1) -> 2012-2-29
```